# Please help with acceleration question

Tags: calculus, mathematical-physics

This is a three-part question to which I have already completed the first two but having trouble with how to calculate the third.

Q/ A particle moves in a straight line so that its position $x$ metres at time $t$ seconds is given by $x=t(t-4)^2.$
Find:
a) The velocity at time $t.$

$$v(t)=dx/dt
=t\times2(t-4)+(t-4)^2
=(t-4)(2t+t-4)
=(t-4)(3t-4).$$

b) The value(s) of $t$ when the particle is instantaneously at rest.

$$x(t)=(t-4),
t=4,$$
and

$$x(t)=(3t-4),
t=4/3.$$

c) What is the acceleration after $4$ seconds?

Part (c) is where I'm having trouble. I have searched through the notes but still unsure on how to calculate. Any help with how to solve would be helpful and appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: I can't really read your solutions to parts $A$ and $B$. Can you use MathJax to type them up please>

Answer (score 0):

The acceleration is the derivative of velocity. So you just differentiate the expression $v(t)$ once and evaluate this when $t=4.$

In addition, I'm not sure I understand what you did in the first two parts. In part (a), you want to differentiate $x(t)$ once to find $v(t).$ In part (b), you want to solve the equation $v(t)=0$ for $t.$